# Unable to convert strings to datetime objects

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was trying to convert some strings to datetime objects. After these strings are converted to datetime objects, I intend to extract the date from these datetime objects based on my timezone. However, when I cast the string to a datetime object, I am getting an error.

```
Code:

cast(json_extract_scalar(data, "$.end_date") as datetime) as end_date_datetime

Error:

Invalid datetime string "2020-12-31T18:29:59Z"
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
`cast(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.end_date') ) as end_date_datetime`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) pages `DATETIME` type doesn't support [time zone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_zones) parameter (the letter `Z` for UTC in your corresponded error description), thus to represent full date/time holder you might consider adopting `TIMESTAMP` instead:

```
cast(json_extract_scalar(data, "$.end_date") as timestamp) as end_date_datetime
```